# Return Zero under column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to have a 'zero' in the column Traffic if there is no data available for the builder in the table. I thought `coalesce` would get me there but it failed on me. Any suggestions.

```
select "Builder", coalesce("Traffic", 0) 
from table
where "Week" = '05/15/2005'
```

The results when I query:

```
select "Builder" "Traffic"
from table
where "Week" = '05/15/2005'

Builder      Traffic
 Mike          10
 Tom           15
 Me            5
```

Desired Results:

```
Builder         Traffic
Jake            0
Mike            10
Tom             15
Me              5
```

Comment: Please post your data set and table structure

Comment: You have a parent table with name as Mike, Jake, Tom, Me?

Comment: It is just one table. Jake has no sales for that week so he is excluded.

Comment: If you have only one table, you have no rows with Jake, so how your query can output Jake 0 row? Or Traffic field counts sales number?

Comment: That is the point, how can I print a '0' value for him. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have only one table, it's no possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COALESCE` works on NULL values, but if **no row** is returned at all, `COALESCE` is never called.

Your 'Jake' has to come from *somewhere*. Assuming you have a table of all possible builders called `builder_names`, you could make it work with a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`:

```
select b."Builder", coalesce(t."Traffic", 0) AS "Traffic"
from   builder_names b
left   join   tbl t ON t.builder = b.builder  -- or some id?
                   AND t."Week" = '05/15/2005';
```

You commented:

> Jake is there in the table but since he has no corresponding data for the week he is excluded.

Then this would help:

```
select "Builder"
     , max(CASE WHEN "Week" = '05/15/2005' THEN "Traffic" ELSE 0 END) AS "Traffic"
from   tbl
group  by "Builder";
```

Assuming:

- You want a *single* row per name.
- "Traffic" is a numeric data type with values > 0.

If there can be multiple rows per builder, and you want them returned, you need a different approach. Your question is a bit light on details.

Either way, the first solution is preferable. With big tables, a clean, normalized schema is much faster.

Asides: I would not use mixed-case identifiers, and I prefer to works with standard ISO 8601 format for date literals (`'2015-12-15'`), which is unambiguous with any locale settings.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, Jake is there in the same table but since he has no corresponding data for the week he is excluded. I want to have a zero next to his name. Is it possible?

Comment: if there is no value for Jake in this week, than there won't be any row at all, so the "Jake"-row can also not have a value with NULL as Traffic

Comment: Yes Traffic is a integer. I applied the second query and it returns a Zero for all the builders now.

Comment: @PythonLearner: Right, you need `max()` not `min()`.

Comment: But if JAKE doesn't exist in that table (never sale for him) you can't extract Jake 0. Is not normalized structure of @PythonLearner

Comment: @JoeTaras: True, but 'Jake' exists according to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

**After comment:**

If you want your desired output you must change your tables structure.

If you have only one table where you store sales, in that you can't retrieve Jake information until Jake has one sale.

If you have two tables, as follow:

```
Table CUSTOMERS
id int
name varchar(20)
```

With these rows:

```
1 Jake
2 Tom
3 Mike
4 Me
```

And another table named SALES with this structure

```
id int
fk_customer int
Traffic int
Week datetime
```

Populated as follow:

```
1, 3, 10, '05/15/2005'
2, 2, 15, '05/15/2005'
3, 4, 5, '05/15/2005'
```

To accomplish your issue you must write this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(s.traffic,0) FROM sales s WHERE s.fk_customer = c.id)
FROM customers c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @table_Name table (Name varchar(200))
Insert Into @table_Name (Name)
Values('Jake'), ('Tom'),('Mike'),('Me')

Declare @table2 table (Id int Identity, Builder varchar(200), Traffic int, [Date] Date)
Insert Into @table2 (Builder,Traffic,[Date])
 Values ('Mike', 10, '05/15/2005'),
('Tom', 15, '05/15/2005'),
('Me', 5, '05/15/2005')

Select      D1.Name, Isnull(D2.Traffic,0) as Traffic
From        @table_Name D1
Left Join   @table2 D2
    On      D1.Name = D2.Builder
```